# How call iPhone app from within iPhone standard call app

Tags: ios4

Here is the situation for the app.

1. My app is calling app.
2. So  from standard or already exist "phone" app of iPhone (which allows us to call )
   i want to launch my calling iPhone app if it satisfy certain condition.

how is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch the built-in phone app from your app, by using the tel: URL invocation.  However, there is no way to get the standard phone app to invoke your application.

Comment: i read somewhere that i can do it by using url requests ...can i use it .